# Unable to resolved messages from properties file at model level in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, properties-file

I already went through the URL: https://www.mkyong.com/spring/spring-propertysources-example/ and found nothing in working in my case.

I've below fields in my model class, but message against the `length.validation.status` is not getting replaced.

I am using Spring Boot `v2.1.5.RELEASE` project and

```
@SafeHtml(whitelistType = WhiteListType.NONE, message = "{html.validation.status}")
@Length(max = ResourceSize.MAX_STATUS, message = "{length.validation.status}")
private String status;
```

Code:

```
@Configuration
@PropertySource("classpath:messages.properties")
@ConfigurationProperties
public class AppConfig {
    @Bean
    public static PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer placeHolderConfigurer() {
        return new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
    }
}
```

**messages.properties**

```
html.validation.intervention=Intervention
html.validation.status=Status
```

**EDIT-1:**

I set the below, but still it's not working.

```
spring:
  application:
    name: Program Catalog

# Mongo DB details
  data:
    mongodb:
      database: XX
      host: localhost
      port: 27017
  profiles:
    active:
    - dev
  messages:
    basename: messages
    fallback-to-system-locale: false
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve the issue by adding the below code. However, we can not used same code while persisting entities in case if you want to give index name.

```
@Bean
public MessageSource messageSource() {
    ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource = new ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource();

    messageSource.setBasename("classpath:messages");
    messageSource.setDefaultEncoding("UTF-8");
    return messageSource;
}

@Bean
public LocalValidatorFactoryBean getValidator() {
    LocalValidatorFactoryBean bean = new LocalValidatorFactoryBean();
    bean.setValidationMessageSource(messageSource());
    return bean;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Configuration property sources and messages sources are different, so you don't need to use `@PropertySource` or `@ConfigurationProperties`.

With Spring Boot you the auto-configured message source is configured with `spring.messages.*` properties. You can use `spring.messages.basename` to set the name (and location) of you message property file(s). By default: `messages.properties` in your classpath. See the [docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-internationalization.html).

However, the `@SafeHtml` is a `hibernate-validator` annotation and that is not resolving messages from Spring. Instead these messages are, by default, from a resource bundle `ValidationMessages.properties` in the root of your classpath. See the [docs](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/validator/reference/en-US/html_single/#section-custom-message-interpolation).

Try creating a file `src/main/resources/ValidationMessages.properties` with the following content

```
html.validation.status=Unsafe HTML
```

that should do it.

Comment: Its still not working yet, Could you please guide ?

Comment: Thanks, spring.messages.basename this logic also doesn't works in my case.. Very strange..

Comment: Could you please share sample example as both the solutions/suggestions are not working yet

Comment: OK, I have no idea why that wouldn't be working. You can take a look at this article https://reflectoring.io/bean-validation-with-spring-boot/ and the corresponding example code: https://github.com/thombergs/code-examples/tree/master/spring-boot/validation